# Is shap compatible with PolynomialFeatures(degree=1)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

I am trying to plot `shap.summary_plot` for polynomial regression but it gives a dimension error

```
<class 'ValueError> shapes (12,) and (11,) are not aligned: 12(dim 0)!= 11(dim 0)
```

```
model = PolynomialFeatures(degree=1)

explainer = shap.Explainer(model = model, feature_names=df.columns,algorithm = 'auto')
```

when I try with LinearExplainer still getting the same error

```
explainer = shap.Explainer(model = model, algorithm = 'auto')
explainer = shap.LinearExplainer(model = model)


shap_values = explainer.shap_values(df)
```

I just want to know if shap is compatible with polynomial regression or not. And if it is compatible how to build the explainer

Comment: What is `model`? Try to give a [mre]. `degree=1` just adds a constant column?...

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, degree=1 is the degree of the polynomial. It is a polynomial regression problem I will try to include a reproducible example

Comment: `PolynomialFeatures` is a transformer, not a regression itself. You need to use it in conjunction with (maybe using a `Pipeline`) some sort of model like `Linear Regression`.

Comment: Or try `AdditiveExplainer()`?